# How to access my web application folder in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have published an asp.net core application to aws elasticbeanstalk and I would like to access the project folder to see the log.txt file however I am not sure how to access the application folder from aws console.

nb: my app logs error to log.txt and I need access to it

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to access the application folder from aws console.

You can't do this directly. You have to ssh into the instance to inspect your `/var/app/current` folder (your application folder).

You could also setup EB to add your `log.txt` to the log files that it monitors and then it will allow you to export it from console.

To do this, you have to use `.ebextensions` and add a config file with:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/log/log.txt
```

Where `/var/app/current/log/log.txt` is the path to `log.txt` of yours. May probably need to adjust it.